# Data within a directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

What do you think should be the value of the expression {{myProperty}}? Shouldn't it be undefined?

```
<div ng-init="myProperty = 'WOW, this is cool'"></div>
<div my-directive>
Inside myDirective, isolate scope: {{ myProperty }}
<div>

<script>
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {}
  };
});
</script>
```

Here http://jsbin.com/diquzuba/1/edit it's a simple example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div my-directive>
Inside myDirective, isolate scope: {{ myProperty }}
<div>
```

This is **not** inside the directive.

```
restrict: 'A',
scope: {}
```

**This** is. A directive is essentially code, sometimes enriched with a template. Do not confuse directives with DOM elements. Imagine this:

```
<div my-directive another-directive yet-another-one>
{{ myProperty }}
<div>
```

If each of those directives had an isolate scope, inside which directive would `{{ myProperty }}` be, if it was really inside a directive?

Comment: Ok, you mean I'm not understanding properly how it works. The scope is not limited by the DIV tags as it is when we define a controller using ng-controller. Am I right? Your last example with the 3 directives was iluminating. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexEpelde Exactly. An isolate scope is not "limited by the DIV tags", as you put it. Scopes, and directives in general,  are a very complex matter and there are some inconsistencies. Your initial assumption is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `{{ myProperty }}` is evaluated on the main template scope as your directive does not define its own template.

If you create a template **with** transclusion it will still display `WOW, this is cool` as transclusion applies the correct parent scope to the transcluded content.

On the other hand, if you define a new template inside your directive without specifying transclusion, and try to use `{{ myProperty }}` inside this template it will be `undefined`.

Comment: I know the attached code it's quite silly but I thought that by defining an isolated scope this way I had a brand new scope object with no 'myProperty' property as there are no bindings. Instead the expression is evaluated and 'WOW, this is cool' is displayed. Where does that value come from?

Comment: It comes from the parent scope, the same scope where `ng-init="myProperty = 'WOW, this is cool'"` is defined. The code inside your div that your `my-directive` is defined on is still evaluated on the parent scope.

Comment: If on the other hand you define a template for your directive, then that template will use the isolated scope and `{{ myProperty }}` will not evaluate.